# How do I check the color of a specific pixel and change text and color of text in an h1 depending on the color of the pixel in HTML5/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, image

I am trying to find the color of a specific pixel and change text and color of text in an h1 depending on the color of the pixel in HTML5 and JavaScript. I have the coordinates of the pixel in question, and the image is from a URL. I already have the CSS classes for the colors that I want it to change it to.

The coordinates are 315, 189.

I tried using code that I found on a different website, but it never explain how to do anything and just gave the code, so it never worked.

```
function getPixel(url, x, y) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = //this is where the url goes;
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  return context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
}
```